# Only home page of wordpress is not opening, memory allocate error Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

only homepage of my website is not opening, showing error:

```
This page isn’t working www.domain.com redirected you too many times.
```

in errors log I can see:

```
[19-Nov-2021 05:17:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 193462272) (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in /hermes/walnacweb07/walnacweb07an/b413/hoc.mwtinccom/wp-includes/media.php on line 3653
[19-Nov-2021 05:17:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 193462272) (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /hermes/walnacweb07/walnacweb07an/b413/hoc.mwtinccom/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5107
```

As I checked `wp_options` table URL is correct and entered without `www` extension

Rest other pages are working, earlier

```
MEMORY_LIMIT was 64M
```

and then I changed it to 256M, but still getting same error.

Can anyone help to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Your WordPress memory settings are in [wp-config.php](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/).

Add `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');`